# Calculate time left between todays date and date in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, automation, sql-update

I am using PHP and MySQL for a very small CMS.

One of the functional requirements is that the system gives back the amount of days left before renewal date (For example how many days left between now and the renewal field in the database)

The process I was going to take was @3AM every morning, go through all the records (via PHP) and update the required field. The trick is that if this figure is <30 (days) then send email to ....who ever.

This seems very impracticable and as it would be in a loop maybe too intense on the database.

If I could have the database make this calculation it would be better (not sure how).

HOWEVER

I will still have to loop through all records anyway to see if there are <30 days before renewal (to send email).

If anyone has a better suggestion, i would be very grateful. Below is some presudo code I would like to do

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM testDB ";
$r = mysql_query($q);

while ( $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {

$rnlDate= stripslashes($a['renewal_Date']); //get Date inserted in table

$thisId= stripslashes($a['id']); // current record id

$timeLeft=$rnlDate-date(); // get time left

if($timeLeft <=30)
{
$makeEmail= createEmail(field_ID); // not sure how to wait until this function completes
}

doUpdate($timeLeft);


function doUpdate($timeLeft)
{
"UPDATE INTO testDB WHERE 'id' =$thisId; VALUES('','$timeLeft',)";
}
```

obviously just passing the idea here, but any other soloutions are very welcome.

Cheers

Comment: You have a typo in the first line (`"`). And where does `$thisId` come from? If it's user input, you should properly escape it to prevent SQL injection. BTW, don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they're [deprecated](http://php.net/mysql_query) (see the red box).

Comment: You should actually try *writing* and *running* your code before you start asking questions about it.

Comment: @Sammitch  - Thanks man, but the purpose of this post was to try and get the theory of the best way to perfom my task rather than dive straight into code. In effect, I dont know the best practice to perform the task. I *could* do it the hacky way, but im trying to get it right. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Why was I marked down for this. I know the code is wrong, but was pusodo code !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL using the [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function, something like

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),column_name) AS diff
FROM table
WHERE id = 'whatever';
```

This will give you the number of days left, plug into a variable $days. Then

```
if(($days > 0) && ($days <30)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Not sure why I was marked down, as I explained this was purley pseudo code, so not overlly worried about misplaced " etc..

@LifeInTheGrey , thanks a million. Your answer implies that I will still have to loop through each record for this, rather than the database perform the calculation, but if it must be done then so be it, or is there a way I can enter that sql into the mySQL and it will perform the command @ a certain time each day ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your query. It's much easier:

```
$q = "SELECT * 
      FROM testDB 
      WHERE renewal_Date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 30 DAY";
```

Comment: Sounds great thanks for the reply.
Is the INTERVAL 30 DAY an actuall mySQL command ?

Comment: Yes, it is. It sounds a bit awkward but it is valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

stripslashes? you really really really need to upgrade your php version. magic_quotes have been disabled by default for a long time now, and having it on is a sign of a badly misconfigured server, and/or badly out-of-date PHP install.

that being said, your query would not be "heavy" or "bad", unless you're dealing with billions of rows...

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE renewal_date  > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND (renewal_date < CURDATE() )
```

should fetch all records where the renewal date falls within the past 30 days.

Comment: Thanks a million man. I am working off the following tutorial[link] http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/[/link]'

If you know of a better (modren) tutorial I would be very grateful. I just need to insert , call, and delete records from database.

Meant to say I am testing on wamp, so that would be my php version ?

Comment: I was looking to get the records if the date falls within NEXT 30 days. I will perform a separate qurie for days < 5 from current date (because different email will be sent. From your example will the following work ? 
`code SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE renewal_date  < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY)  `